# Ruby on Rails config object structure debugging in RubyMine cannot find my config items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine

If I configure something in my Rails config like:

```
  config.foo = 'bar'
  config.assets.foo = 'bar2'
```

...and I set a watch and break points on config, I don't seem to be able to ever see my item(s) in the config object.  I expect to see them added to a collection within the config object, or a property of the config object, and can't see them.

Can anyone tell me how to see my custom config items in the debugger watching the Rails config object?

The items are there as they are extracted if read out of the config, but via the debugger and expanding the config object, I just cannot find my items anywhere.

Comment: Where are these being set? `config/application.rb`? `config/environments/*.rb`?